# HTML5: Input Type File - read image data

Tags: javascript, html, input

I'd like to read "width" and "heigth" of an image file that I pick with HTML input element (type is file). My problem is, that I get the values 0 / 0 when I pick an image file for the first time. When I pick a second image file (doesn't matter which one), I get the correct values for width and height for the first/previous image.

How can I make sure to instantly get width and heigth of the image file I picked?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

 <input type="file" id="fileInput" accept="image/*" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script>
  var img = new Image();
  //set input back to default on refresh:
  $('#fileInput')[0].value = "";
  
  function handleFiles(fileList) {
   if (!fileList.length) {
    console.log("No files selected!");
   } else {
    console.log(fileList.length);
    console.log(fileList[0]);
    
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileList[0]);
    
    console.log("src: " + img.src);
    console.log("width: " + img.width + " / height: " + img.height);
    
    img.onload = function() {
     window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
    }
   }
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I marked your answer useful, but get this message:"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 3):

You need to get width/height in the `onload` event (`img.onload = function() {...}`)

*Note, as [@guest271314](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318829/html5-input-type-file-read-image-data/42318881?noredirect=1#comment71791160_42318881) pointed out, use `naturalWidth`/`naturalHeight` instead of `width`/`height`*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <input type="file" id="fileInput" accept="image/*" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    var img = new Image();
    //set input back to default on refresh:
    $('#fileInput')[0].value = "";

    function handleFiles(fileList) {
      if (!fileList.length) {
        console.log("No files selected!");
      } else {
        console.log(fileList.length);
        console.log(fileList[0]);

        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileList[0]);

        console.log("src: " + img.src);

        img.onload = function() {
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);

          console.log("width: " + img.naturalWidth + " / height: " + img.naturalHeight);

        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```